# issue with including module to angularjs

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am trying to add 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination' module to my project :

```
angular.module('ClientSideApp',['ngRoute','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']).config( function($routeProvider) {
```

so like that the console shows Failed to instantiate module angularUtils.directives.dirPagination due to:....

i tried also to add the module in my controller file

```
angular.module('ClientSideApp',['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']).controller('afficheCtrl', function($scope,$http,$location) {
```

and it is the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to add the dependency to the controller file, just make sure you have the necessary references to **`'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'`**

```
<script src="dirPagination.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/qBYiKyyv8I2ygu8uRUd1?p=preview)**